# Add new data frame column conditioning on second data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have two data frames which I am trying to integrate. The first data frame looks like:

```
df1=data.frame(Gene=c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5"),
              CHR=c(1,4,5,6,7),
              START=c(1000,5000,10000,15000,20000), 
              STOP=c(2000,6000,11000,16000,21000), 
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df1
Gene CHR START  STOP
gene1   1  1000  2000
gene2   4  5000  6000
gene3   5 10000 11000
gene4   6 15000 16000
gene5   7 20000 21000
```

The second data frame looks like:

```
df2=data.frame(Disorder=c("A","A","A","B","C"),
              Locus=c(1,2,3,1,1),
              Chr=c(1,1,6,4,1),
              Locus.Start=c(157,1500,14600,30000,2300), 
              Locus.Stop=c(800,2400,15900,35000,7000), 
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df2
Disorder Locus Chr Locus.Start Locus.Stop
     A     1   1         157        800
     A     2   1        1500       2400
     A     3   6       14600      15900
     B     1   4       30000      35000
     C     1   1         900       3000
```

What I am trying to do is make a column in df1 which says where chromosome matches between df1 and df2 (CHR == Chr) and the position of the gene (START or STOP) in df1 spans the locus of df2 (between the values of Locus.Start and Locus.Stop), print disorder and locus.

So, 
where df1$CHR == df2Chr AND

((df1$START >= df2$Locus.Start AND df1$START <= df2$Locus.Stop) OR

(df1$STOP >= df2$Locus.Start AND df1$STOP <= df2$Locus.Stop))

print Disorder Locus, otherwise print NA.

This would result in a table looking like:

```
> df1
 Gene CHR START  STOP  Map
gene1   1  1000  2000  A loc2, C loc1 
gene2   4  5000  6000  NA
gene3   5 10000 11000  NA
gene4   6 15000 16000  A loc3
gene5   7 20000 21000  NA
```

So far, I have just been trying to get anything close to that (so accepting A loc2 C loc1 as the last column for example) and have tried things like:

```
 df1$Map<-ifelse(df1$CHR == df2$Chr & 
         ((df1$START >= df2$Locus.Start & df1$START <= df2$Locus.Stop)|
         (df1$STOP >= df2$Locus.Start & df1$STOP <= df2$Locus.Stop)),
          print(df2$Disorder " loc"df2$Locus),NA)
```

Is there a way of referencing between two data frames like this, to use information from df2 to make a new column in df1?

Many thanks for any help received.

Comment: Looks like you need a non-equi join, but I find the conditions to not match with the examples provided , e.g. For the first row in 'df1', the 'Chr' matches the 1, 2, and 5 of 'CHR' in 'df2', but the `START >= Locus.Start`fails in 1st two and only 5th matches, similarly there are other conditions having the same issue

Comment: I'm wondering if I could phrase it better... as it is if START or STOP is between the values of Locus.Start and Locus.Stop (and CHR == Chr) then I want to print, otherwise NA...

Comment: So in my "example of what it would look like", gene1 would return A2 because CHR==Chr, and STOP is between Locus.Start and Locus.Stop. And C1 because both START and STOP are between those values. gene4 would return A3 because CHR==Chr and START is between Locus.Start and Locus Stop. So the condition is that CHR must match Chr, and either START or STOP must be between the values of Locus.Start and Locus Stop. (i.e. there needs to be some overlap of the START - STOP and Locus.Start - Locus.Stop number ranges)

Comment: You can do a full-join or left_join and then create the conditions, but unfortunately, from the example it is not matching i.e. try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% left_join( df2, by = c('CHR' = 'Chr')) %>% mutate(i1 = (START >= Locus.Start & START <= Locus.Stop)|(STOP >= Locus.Start & STOP <= Locus.Stop) )`

Comment: e.g. in your expected you have included the first row of `Map` as `A` and `C`.  Not sure how you get with the same expression because `(STOP >= Locus.Start & STOP <= Locus.Stop)` (2000 < 2300)

Comment: I did wonder if it was too much to attempt in one take. So I will follow your advice and try joining first, then creating conditions. This post is probably partly suffering from me trying to modify the data so it wasn't real data. But, I did create the data to mimic what I would see in my data (i.e. the START and STOP wouldn't necessarily both be between Location.Start and Location.Stop, but if one of them was, then I count it as overlapping and want to print what Disease and Locus it is overlapping with). But. I shall try breaking the problem down into pieces!

Comment: The `OR` join may  also be done in `sql` using `sqldf`